# Simplify using Geometric series

Tags: geometric-series

Can this be simplified using Geometric series?

$$\Large\sum_{a=2}^\infty x^a\left[2(pq)^{\frac{a-2}2}+p^2+q^2\right]$$

thanks!

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I want to be able to see it clearly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Not that I'm second-guessing your decision to revert your stylistic choice, but wouldn't it make more sense to increase the font in your browser than to write `\Large` on your own or others' work if you want to see it better, since this action only affects a tiny proportion of all the math on the site? Accommodating individual needs is better handled with individual settings than adjusting defaults.

Comment: @Mario: I could be wrong, but I suspect that it’s far from just an individual need. Having used a variety of browsers on a variety of machines, I’ve come to the conclusion that the smallest elements of such complex expressions are almost invariably too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split it into two summations:

$$\Large\sum_{a=2}^\infty 2\sqrt{pq}^{a-2}x^a+(p^2+q^2)\sum_{a=2}^\infty x^a\;.$$

The second summation is a simple geometric series, and the first can be rewritten as

$$\large\frac2{pq}\sum_{a=2}^\infty\left(\sqrt{pq}x\right)^a\;,$$

another geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solve $\sum_a x^a$ and $\sum_a (x\sqrt{pq})^a$ in terms of geometric series, which will give you your series. Note you have to check to make sure the series converges.